# POST data from multiple forms in single request using Node.js

Tags: node.js, express, post, http-post

I'm trying to send a POST request to an API from multiple forms at once. Essentially I have a site where users will input data to multiple locations **before** clicking a button to run a calculation. Clicking the button will ideally send a POST request to the API containing all the information the user has input from various places.

Within the body of `index.html` I've tried the following, effectively trying to get both forms to POST to the same address, but only including a `submit` button with one.

```
<form action="/" method="post" name="myForm">
  <div>
    Here is some text at the top of the form...
  </div>
  <input type="text" name="num1" class="inp1" placeholder="First Number">
  <input type="text" name="num2" class="inp2" placeholder="Second Number">
          
  <button type="submit" name="submit">
      calculator
  </button>
</form>

<form action="/" method="post" name="myForm">
  <div>
    Here is a 2nd form
  </div>
  <input type="text" name="num1" class="inp1" placeholder="Third Number">
  <input type="text" name="num2" class="inp2" placeholder="Fourth Number">
</form>
```

My Node.js code to spin up a server and look at the POST request:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const app = express();

app.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true,
  })
);

const tempResult = fs.readFileSync(
  `${__dirname}/templates/overview.html`,
  "utf-8"
);

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send(tempResult);
});

app.post("/", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.send(tempResult);
});

const port = 3000;

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`App running on port ${port}...`);
});
```

In the console this simply returns:

```
{
  num1: val1,
  num2: val2,
  submit: ''
}
```

Where `val1` and `val2` are the inputs to `index.html` for the **first form only**. What am I missing here? How can I get the values from both forms in one call?

Comment: You should nest all the inputs in a single form.

Answer (score 0):

As alluded to by [@Ipizzinidev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13211263/lpizzinidev) the solution here lies in putting the form right at the top of the body.

```html
<body>
  <form action="/" method="POST">
    <div>
      Here is some text at the top of the form...
    </div>
    <input type="text" name="num1" class="inp1" placeholder="First Number">
    <input type="text" name="num2" class="inp2" placeholder="Second Number">
    <input type="text" name="num3" class="inp3" placeholder="Third Number">
    <input type="text" name="num4" class="inp4" placeholder="Fourth Number">
      
    <button type="submit" name="submit">
      calculator
    </button>
  </form>
</body>
```

Inside this form you can do the usual HTML stuff and then after hitting `submit` it will return the following:

```js
{
  num1: val1,
  num2: val2,
  num3: val3,
  num4: val4,
  submit: ''
}
```

It always seems so simple in hindsight!